# Vertica DB user permissions becomes active only after connection is closed

Tags: vertica

I am using Vertica Analytic Database v7.1.1-12. I faced the issue then I am granting permissions to the role and then assigning role to the user and the permissions are finally granted only after I close the connection. Is there any way to flush privileges or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

To enable the newly granted role you need to issue the command `SET ROLE mynewrole` in that user's session. If you need this role to be effective every time you may want to change the user's default role: `ALTER USER ... DEFAULT ROLE ...`.

References:

- [Enabling roles](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Security/DBUsersAndPrivileges/EnablingRoles.htm)
- [Changing default role](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Security/DBUsersAndPrivileges/DefaultRolesForDatabaseUsers.htm)